# Rounding to the nearest 10

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to calculate the check digit of a GTIN-8 barcode. Below is my code:

```
def generate():
    Valid = False
    while not Valid:
        # ask the user to enter 7 digits and check that the input is correct.
        GTIN = input("Please enter a 7 digit integer")
        if len(GTIN) == 7 and  GTIN.isdigit():
            print("You have entered it correctly")
            Valid = True
        else:
            print("That is not 7 integers. Please enter 7 digits")

    times_together = int(GTIN[0])*3+int(GTIN[1])+int(GTIN[2])*3+ \
                    int(GTIN[3])+int(GTIN[4])*3+int(GTIN[5])+int(GTIN[6])*3

    print(times_together)
```

The function multiplies the input digits respectively by 3 then 1. For instance, if I enter 1324562, it will correctly return the value 43. I need the program to subtract the value (43) from the rounded-up multiple of 10 value (50) and append the result (7) to the input digits as a check digit i.e. 13245627.

I am a python beginner so I want to do this in simple code without importing packages such as `math` and `ceil`. I want the calculations to be assigned to variables to see what is happening.

Comment: The answer to the title is `round(x, -1)` - but the body seems to describe a lot of other different things. Unless you can clarify this, I've voted to close as **unclear what you're asking**.

Comment: Change to "next greater multiple of 10" to stave off the critics

Comment: Try `int((n+9)/10)*10`

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you want now. Something like `units = int(str(x)[-1])` and `check_digit = 10 - units`? This question could still do with improving, mainly just by reducing to the actual question.